# Composition or aggregation in this example

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I know the theory but obviously when it comes to real world, I just do not know. In the following example is the relation between game and player/board a composition (they are instantionated inside the Game class)? And between a board and a pawn - aggregation, because the board can exist with 0 pawns?

```
Class Game
{
   Player p;
   Gameboard b;
  void Start()
  {
     p=new Player();
     b=new Gameborad();
  }
}

class Gameboard
{
   List<pawn> listOfpawns=new List<pawn>();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between composition and aggregation is not whether a board can exist with zero pawns, but whether pawns can exist without boards, and also whether players and game boards can exist without a game.

In other words, if destroying a game will destroy all the players and boards then you have composition.  If players and boards can live outside a game, then you have aggregation.

If destroying a board with destroy the pawns then you have composition.  If pawns can live without a board, you have aggregation.

In general, if destroying the container destroys its elements, that's composition.  Elements whose existence is not dependent on the container are said to be held by aggregation.

The classic examples of aggregation are:

- Countries within alliances, because countries continue to exist if the alliance is disbanded
- People within organizations, since the people still live when the organization ceases to exist

The classic examples of composition are:

- The schedule(s) of a person, since if the person goes away, the schedule does too.

Comment: Also it would mean that is all composition - the  players cannot exist without the game and neither can the board. The pawns too have no meaning as they can be only placed on the board. Does it matter if a e.g. a player has method that takes a pawn as an argument?

Comment: If the concept of player has no meaning at all outside of a game, then yes, model this as composition.  But you can imagine a case where a single player object can participate in many games, in which case you would use aggregation.  It's totally up to you.  OBTW since your question is about UML, why not use an undecorated arrow and ignore the whole issue?  Is it that important really? ;-)  ... as to whether pawns are passed to player methods, this kind of thing was captured in the old pre-UML Booch notation (the P-in-the-box arrowhead) but AFAIK UML doesn't directly support it.

Answer (score 0):

**Composition**

An object contain other objects, stored by value. These are usually elements you think as internal to the object holding them, like a cardDeck object has card objects. Even if the deck isn't initially filled, the objects mostly have purpose only **inside** the holding object.

**Aggregation**

An object contains references to other objects, the aggregated objects are something that exist out in the program in another context, and the parent object is just holding them for organizational or functional reasons. Example given in the below site reference is a plane that holds person objects. The persons may come and go, and may be used in other parts of the program.

**In This Case:**

Your example I'd say falls more under Composition. Much like the deck of cards, the pawns have little meaning outside of the game board.

**Terminology**

The literalness "by value" or "by reference" depends on the language, when people say one or the other in this context they use it to refer to how strong an owning relationship the parent has.

Of course in Java all objects are stored by reference, But! As soon as no references to an object exist, it's eventually culled by the GC. The airplane is likely to be holding the only reference to the engine, so the engine dies when the airplane is removed. People can have other things referencing them beyond the airplane, so you can think of it less like the Airplane is holding them directly.

(Reference http://atomicobject.com/pages/Aggregation)

Comment: Hmm still do not get it, the article mentiones "by value" (composition) but their example about airplane and engine (aggregation) - what would be the airplane without the engine, or rather the engine outside of the airplane?

Comment: The literalness "by value" or "by reference" depends on the language, it just goes back to that idea the other answerer was mentioning of whether the object "lives" after the parent dies. In Java, as soon as no references to an object lists, it's eventually culled by the GC. The airplane is likely to be holding the only reference to the engine, so the engine dies when the airplane is removed. People can have other things referencing them beyond the airplane, so you can think of it less like the Airplane is holding them directly.

Comment: Added the above into my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ray and Vigilant are right but what is right for you depends more on the (goal of the) Application then it does on the objects itself.

- Game/Player:

  - If the application is an ad-hoc Game: Player would be Composite
  - If the application does more with the Players (keeps scores/ranking): Player
    would be Aggregation

or

- Airplane/Engine:

  - If the application is a Airline: Engine would be Composite
  - If the application is Maintenance: Engine would be Aggregation